# RNN parameters not updating?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network, pytorch

I'm very new to PyTorch, and fairly new to neural networks in general.
I was trying to build a neural net that can guess gender given name, and I based off of the PyTorch RNN tutorial that judges nationality.
I got the code to run without errors, but the loss hardly changes, making me think the weights aren't updating...
Is this a problem with my input/output/target tensor setup? Or perhaps something wrong with my training function? I'm very lost, and any help would be appreciated :cold_sweat:
Here's my code:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals, print_function, division  
from io import open  
import glob  
import unicodedata  
import string  
import torch  
import torchvision  
import torch.nn as nn  
import torch.optim as optim  
import random  
from torch.autograd import Variable  

"""------GLOBAL VARIABLES------"""

all_letters = string.ascii_letters + " .,;'"
num_letters = len(all_letters)
all_names = {}
genders = ["Female", "Male"]

"""-------DATA EXTRACTION------"""

def findFiles(path):
    return glob.glob(path)

def unicodeToAscii(s):
    return ''.join(
        c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFD', s)
        if unicodedata.category(c) != 'Mn'
        and c in all_letters
    )

# Read a file and split into lines
def readLines(filename):
    lines = open(filename, encoding='utf-8').read().strip().split('\n')
    return [unicodeToAscii(line) for line in lines]

for file in findFiles("/home/andrew/PyCharm/PycharmProjects/CantStop/data/names/*.txt"):
    gender = file.split("/")[-1].split(".")[0]
    names = readLines(file)
    all_names[gender] = names

"""-----DATA INTERPRETATION-----"""

def nameToTensor(name):
    tensor = torch.zeros(len(name), 1, num_letters)
    for index, letter in enumerate(name):
        tensor[index][0][all_letters.find(letter)] = 1
    return tensor

def outputToGender(output):
    gender, gender_index = output.data.topk(1)
    if gender_index[0][0] == 0:
        return "Female"
    return "Male"

"""------NETWORK SETUP------"""

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        #Layer 1
        self.Lin1 = nn.Linear(input_size+hidden_size, int((input_size+hidden_size)/2))
        self.ReLu1 = nn.ReLU()
        self.Batch1 = nn.BatchNorm1d(int((input_size+hidden_size)/2))
        #Layer 2
        self.Lin2 = nn.Linear(int((input_size+hidden_size)/2), output_size)
        self.ReLu2 = nn.ReLU()
        self.Batch2 = nn.BatchNorm1d(output_size)
        self.softMax = nn.LogSoftmax()
        #Hidden layer
        self.HidLin = nn.Linear(input_size+hidden_size, hidden_size)
        self.HidReLu = nn.ReLU()
        self.HidBatch = nn.BatchNorm1d(hidden_size)

    def forward(self, input, hidden):
        comb = torch.cat((input, hidden), 1)
        hidden = self.HidBatch(self.HidReLu(self.HidLin(comb)))
        output1 = self.Batch1(self.ReLu1(self.Lin1(comb)))
        output2 = self.softMax(self.Batch2(self.ReLu2(self.Lin2(output1))))
        return output2, hidden

    def initHidden(self):
        return Variable(torch.zeros(1, self.hidden_size))

NN = Net(num_letters, 128, 2)

"""------TRAINING------"""

def getRandomTrainingEx():
    gender = genders[random.randint(0, 1)]
    name = all_names[gender][random.randint(0, len(all_names[gender])-1)]
    gender_tensor = Variable(torch.LongTensor([genders.index(gender)]))
    name_tensor = Variable(nameToTensor(name))
    return gender_tensor, name_tensor, gender

def train(input, target):
    hidden = NN.initHidden()

    loss_func = nn.NLLLoss()

    alpha = 0.01

    NN.zero_grad()

    for i in range(input.size()[0]):
        output, hidden = NN(input[i], hidden)

    loss = loss_func(output, target)
    loss.backward()
    for w in NN.parameters():
        w.data.add_(-alpha, w.grad.data)

    return output, loss

for i in range(5000):
    gender_tensor, name_tensor, gender = getRandomTrainingEx()
    output, loss = train(name_tensor, gender_tensor)

    if i%500 == 0:
        print("Guess: %s, Correct: %s, Loss: %s" % (outputToGender(output), gender, loss.data[0]))
```

And here's the output:

```
Guess: Male, Correct: Male, Loss: 0.6931471824645996
Guess: Male, Correct: Female, Loss: 0.7400936484336853
Guess: Male, Correct: Male, Loss: 0.6755779385566711
Guess: Female, Correct: Female, Loss: 0.6648257374763489
Guess: Male, Correct: Male, Loss: 0.6765623688697815
Guess: Female, Correct: Male, Loss: 0.7330614924430847
Guess: Female, Correct: Female, Loss: 0.6565149426460266
Guess: Male, Correct: Female, Loss: 0.6946508884429932
Guess: Female, Correct: Female, Loss: 0.6621525287628174
Guess: Male, Correct: Male, Loss: 0.6662092804908752

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: What are the loss and accuracies you get while training?

Comment: Also, Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you change `add_` to `sub_`. add_ may lead you away from optima point.

```
w.data.sub_(f.grad.data * alpha)
```

Because, there is a subtraction in weight update formula.

[image: updating]

By the ways, try increase/decrease alpha to 0.1 0.05 0.01. If alpha too large, it may miss the optima point. If alpha to small, it take too long.

Comment: Good call on changing the learning rate. What concerns me is that the loss doesn't change continuously... it hopscotches around from 0.6 to 0.5 to 0.7, this sort of thing...

Comment: perhaps you should include your dataset in the code, or post your dataset here (you may use https://gist.github.com for text file). So we can debug your code.